# Get multi level first child XML Element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to get a first child of a XML document (without knowing the exact names of the nodes), multi levels deep.

I'm porting some code from JS to Python. This was the JS code:

```js
let document = XmlService.parse(response);
let root = document.getRootElement();
return root.getContent(0).getContent(0).getContent(0).getContent(0);
```

I'm using ElementTree in Python, I now have this:

```py
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(response.text))
root = tree.getroot()
print(list(root.iter())[0].tag)
```

This gets the tag of the first element, good.
But when I try to get deeper, like this:

```py
print(list(list(root.iter())[0].iter())[0].tag)
```

Pretty ugly code, but this line produces the same as the previous one. The tag of the first element at level 1 is shown, not the tag of the first element at level 2.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code from @Chandan Maurya showed that I can just do rootElement[0].
So I just did this:

```
root[0][0][0].tag
```

And this works. A recursive function is not needed in my case because I know how deep I need to go.